# reinventing exec in java

Tags: java, shell, command-line

I'm trying to redefine exec in java. But I'm not too sure how command prompt is reading the set of split strings. Assuming in command prompt, I enter "Java, path, arg1, arg 2... arg n" where split[1] is the path which will be main.java or just main. But it seems that not all arguments are being passed. Test is a class that excepts three arguments. And when it accepts three arguments, it implements executes another main method called Test, which is a test case. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with re-implementing exec. But I would just like to execute another main class.

```
PROMPT\>exec C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test.java 2 2 2
C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test.java
C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test.java 2 2 2 Is not a file
PROMPT\>exec java C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test.java 2 2 2
java
PROMPT\>exec java C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test 2 2 2
java
java C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test 2 2 2 Is not a file
PROMPT\>exec java C:\Users\maste\workspace\Sh3ll\src\Test 2 2 2
```

---

```
  public Execute(String name){
      if(name.length() != 0)
      {
          f(name);
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println("No file was entered");
      return;
      }
  }


  private void f(String s){
      String[] split = s.split(" ");
      File f = new File(split[1]);
      System.out.println(split[0]);
      if(f.isFile())
      {
          if(f.canExecute())
             {
              try{
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec(split[1]);
              }catch(IOException e)
              {
                  System.out.println("NO Bueno");
              }
             }
          else if(!f.canExecute())
          {
              System.out.println(s + " is not an exectuable");
              return;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println(s + " Is not a file");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `split[1]` to `exec()`.  You're not doing anything with `split[2]`, `split[3]`, etc., so it shouldn't be surprised that the arguments aren't being passed.  There are overloads of `exec` that take `String` arrays, so you'll need to build an array and pass that.  I won't guarantee that that will make things work, but you'll need to start with that.  See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-).

Comment: Don't you mean you're "writing a shell in Java", not "reinventing exec"?

Comment: I certainly hope you aren't really "reinventing `exec`".

Comment: Yes writing a shell, thank you. And I also tried sending split by itself through exec.  Should I be using a loop?

Comment: If you want to pass the entire array to `exec()`, you can pass the result of `split()`.  If you want to pass most of the array but leave off the first element, for instance, you'll have to create a new array and copy elements from the result of `split()` (perhaps using one of the utilities in the `Arrays` class).